# Isolate https://*something*.com from a bunch of text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a :`string BunchOfText` which contains a link which starts with `https://` and ends with `.com`.
 I need to isolate that link and to put it in another string.
Any suggestions how?
EDIT :
My text looks like this:

> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
>   https://mydomain/RANDOMGENERATEDTEXT.com
>   Why do we use it?

I want to have a new string

```
string link ="https://mydomain/RANDOMGENERATEDTEXT.com"
```

By the time of this edit, user : serhiyb, gave me a perfect answer!

Comment: Do *all* the strings start with `https://` and end with `.com`? In that case you could do `myUrl.Substring( 8, myUrl.Length - 12 )`

Comment: Could you show us the string and what you've tried?

Comment: @Bob Kaufman I have a bunch of text and in the middle of the text I have a link  whose length is not constant.  Therefore I have to isolate that part by "start with" and "end with".

Comment: Please edit your question to include/clarify this important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Regex linkParser = new Regex(@"https:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.com\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string rawString = "some text with https://go.com link in it";
foreach(Match m in linkParser.Matches(rawString))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
```

Live demo:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zg8UDj

It will find all links that start with `https` and are subdomain of `.com` zone.

Answer (score 0):

you can just crop the string as following:

```
string text = "https://what you want to extract.com";
string extr = text.Substring( 8, text.Length-12 );
```

`extr` is the string you want as I think.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `IndexOf()` twice and extract the "in between".

Something like:

```
string AllText = "fhdsfhhttps://what you want to extract.comDFDSFDSF";

var FirstIndex = AllText.IndexOf("https://");
var SecondIndex = AllText.IndexOf(".com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex` to locate the links, and then a group inside the link to get just the part that you want.

Regex: `https:\/\/((www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256})\.com`

The part in the parenthesis is the group.

In C# code, this is used like this:

```
Regex regex=new Regex(@"https:\/\/((www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256})\.com");
foreach(Match match in regex.Matches("test for https://www.domain.com"))
    string partBetween=match.Groups[1].Value; // www.domain
```